# probability that 5 comes before 7

Tags: probability

In the following question [image]

What they have done after the line

'the probability of getting neither 5 nor 7'

Comment: Please [add context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that a $5$ came before a $7$. How could this have happened? Well...

- The first roll could have been a $5$.
- The second roll could have been a $5$. This means that the first roll must have been neither a $5$ nor a $7$.
- The third roll could have been a $5$. This means that the previous two rolls must both have been neither a $5$ nor a $7$.
- The fourth roll could have been a $5$. This means that the previous three rolls must each have been neither a $5$ nor a $7$.
- ...
- The $n$th roll could have been a $5$. This means that the previous $n - 1$ rolls must each have been neither a $5$ nor a $7$.

Adding up each case's probability yields an infinite geometric series.